# Scala: What is the simplest implementation of method 'mystery' can I get?

Tags: scala

I wrote a quite strange method in Scala.

```
def mystery(p: Int => String => Boolean): Int = ???
```

And now I cannot figure out what implementation and parameter value it  should have.

So what is the simplest implementation this method can have? And what is the value we can pass to it?

My try:

```
def mystery(p: Int => String => Boolean): Int = {
    val m = (x1: Int) => p(x1)
    val n = (x2: String) => m(_)(x2)
    val k = (x3: Boolean) => p(_)(_)(x3)
    if (k) 1 else 0
}
```

Comment: please don't remove parts of your question answers are already referring to.

Comment: But if that part is wrong, I still should leave it as is?

Comment: if you post something and people refer to it, and then you delete it, you're wasting people's time.

Comment: you can always add a mention that you realised something you wrote turned out to be mislead.

Comment: Scala trolling :-)))

Answer (score 0):

How about this?  `p` is a function, so to use it you need to pass it parameters.  The parameters are curried, and the function is equivalent to `Int => (String => Boolean)`. You give it an `Int` first, and it returns a function `String => Boolean`.  So you give *that* a `String`, and it returns a `Boolean`.

```
def mystery(p: Int => String => Boolean): Int = {
  val a = p(1)
  val b = a("2")
  if(b) 1 else 0
}

val f: Int => String => Boolean = (i: Int) => (s: String) => i.toString == s

mystery(f)
```

In your version, `m`, `n`, and `k` are all defined as functions.  So, for example, when you say `if (k)` it doesn't make sense because `if` takes a `Boolean`, but you're giving it a function.

Comment: How can I get an access to `x`, where `x` is a value of `p(x)`?

Comment: I'm not sure you're question makes sense.  If you are calling `p(x)`, then you know `x`.  If `p(x)` was called somewhere else, then some new value has been computed and the old is gone.

Comment: In that case my signature is totally wrong: `p: Int => String => Boolean`.

Comment: If I don't want to use constants in `val a = p(1); val b = a("abc")` can I get access to parameters of passed function? Somethink like this `val a = (x1: Int) => p(x1); val b = (x2: String) => a(_)(x2)`

Comment: @barbara: you need to find a programming tutorial; or at least one on higher order functions; what you're asking in the previous comment is nonsense.